# yes or no ending loop not displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I have a "would you like to play again" feature. For some reason when I put no, it runs it through the not yes or no loop before stopping the code. Why is it doing this?  Here is my code:

```
  again = input('Would you like to play again?\t')
  while again != ('yes') or ('no'):
    print ('Error code 1: Please try again!')
    again = input('Would you like to play again?\t')
    if again == ('yes') or ('no'):
      break
  if again == ('no'):
    break
```

Here is my output:

```
Would you like to play again?   no
Error code 1: Please try again!
Would you like to play again?   no
```

Comment: `again != ('yes') or ('no')` is not the right way to test multiple values.

Comment: Can you please explain why not?  The other article did not explain this.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Because Python isn't like English.  In English we can say "Is X equal to Y or Z", and it's understood that the intent is to compare X to Y and also X to Z.  But in Python, you have to fully spell out each condition: `x == y or x == z`.

Comment: But what exactly is wrong with the statement?  Shouldn't any statement that is not yes or no go thru the loop?

Comment: Oh.  That makes sense.  Thanks so much for clarifying.

Comment: And the linked answer does say that, but it's a long answer and that bit is easy to miss.

Comment: I'm stilling getting this:Would you like to play again?   no
debug
Error code 1: Please try again!
Would you like to play again?   no . Even after chaning my code toif again != ('no') or again != ('yes'):
    print('debug')
    while again != ('yes') or again != ('no'):
      print ('Error code 1: Please try again!')
      again = input('Would you like to play again?\t')
      if again == ('yes') or ('no'):
        break
  if again == ('no'):
    break

Comment: sorry, that's really hard to read.

Comment: No matter what your input is, `if again != ('no') or again != ('yes')` will __always__ be true.  You want `and` instead of `or`.